# Xfce theme mismatch

Tags: themes, xfce

Can someone please help me get these two windows to match:

[image]

I was able to do it last time I used xfce but for the life of me I cannot remember how. I would like them both to be the dark theme.

Comment: Suggestion: You should include what theme are you using, so that anyone who use the same theme can point out how to configure the theme properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a theme that is available for both, Gtk2 and Gtk3.